# Java stored procedure running infinitely

Tags: oracle11g, java-stored-procedures

I'm calling a java stored procedure from oracle. After i called execute() method it is never coming out of SP execution and locking the tables. But after i stop the server, the records are getting inserted into tables. Any one face similar issue?

Comment: Are you using multithreading in the SP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. Before calling the SP, i'm doing many insert and update statements and they are locking 5 to 6 tables. I committed the transaction before calling the SP and after that my SP is running fine.